# Django ORM: How to filter on many-to-many relation without filtering related objects

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have some Django models like following:

```
class Film:
    genre = models.ManyToManyField("Genre", blank=True)

class Genre(TimeStampedModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    slug = AutoSlugField(max_length=55, unique=True, populate_from="name")
```

Now, I want to select all films which are associated with the genre "Theatre" and get a list of all their associated genres:

```
In [1]: from apps.base.models import Film, Genre

In [2]: qs = Film.objects.filter(genre__slug='theatre')

In [3]: set(qs.values_list("genre__slug", flat=True))
Out[3]: {'theatre'}
```

However, this is not the result that I want. Looking at the genres of the first film returned as part of the queryset, we can see more genres:

```
In [4]: set(qs[0].genre.all().values_list("slug", flat=True))
Out[4]: {'dance', 'education', 'theatre', 'video-recording'}
```

How can I efficiently filter the films to those associated with the genre "Theatre" and retrieve their associated genres?

Answer (score 1):

A solution to this is a query on Genre, filtering by the Films returned earlier:

```
In[23]: set(Genre.objects.filter(film__in=qs))
Out[23]: 
{<Genre: Dance>,
 <Genre: Education>,
 <Genre: Theatre>,
 <Genre: Video Recording>}
```

I guess accessing that information directly from the original query is not possible as the other genres are filtered out by the `WHERE` clause that is used to select the films.

However, this approach seems a bit inefficient if `prefetch_related('genre')` is used, because it will result in the same query being performed twice, once for `prefetch_related('genre')` and once for the application described above.